# Can't type inside EditText after setting visibility gone

Tags: android

I have an EditText:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/editWord"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="text" />
```

In my activity I'm able to fire text changed events in this way:

```
editWord.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        //do stuff
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
         //do stuff
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        //do stuff
    }
});
```

I need to hide the EditText and I tried adding this in my XML:

```
android:visibility="invisible"
```

After this the edit text disappears but events aren't fired. Why? How can I hide my EditText without "lose" events firing?

Comment: How are you changing the `EditText`'s text once its visibility is set to `invisible`?

Comment: Setting this in my activity manifest `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible"` and `editWord.requestFocus()` in my activity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just set the alpha to 0 in the xml of your `EditText`? `android:alpha="0"`

It should have the same visual effect of `android:visibility="invisible"` but will still call the `addTextChangedListener` methods.